# how it is possible implementing TimeLimit FIFO in c++

Tags: c++, time, limit, fifo

i need to implement a time limit fifo in c++.this fifo used to message passing between objects.

i don't have any idea for this.please give me an idea or introduce any source.

Thanks alot

Comment: use a queue, std::queue it is very useful

Comment: What is a "time limit" FIFO?

Comment: say we want to implement a porotocol such as a sip.
transaction need a timer to start and end.when we want to start timer e care it and queue.after the timer expired it's method must be executed and report something to another object reside on top of transaction(Dialogs).